# Layout occupies more than desired

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want an included RelativeLayout acts like footer but I don't get it like this and that's what I get.
[image]

And that'S what I'd like to get.
[image]

I copy my Layouts so that you can say me what I'm making wrong

Main xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.nutiteq.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/compass_north"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_compass_64" />            
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/current_position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/zoom_in"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/show_my_location_button_style"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_location_found" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/zoom_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/zoom_out"  
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"            
            android:background="@drawable/show_my_location_button_style"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_zoom_in" />  
    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/zoom_out"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                      
            android:background="@drawable/show_my_location_button_style"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_zoom_out" />                            

    <include **<!-- Here I Include the next Layout -->**
        android:id="@+id/speed_display_layout"
        layout="@layout/display_tablet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_below="@+id/zoom_out" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"   
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_left_list"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/metallic_silver"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_right_list"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/metallic_silver"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />    

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the minor Layout to include

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/display_rel_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tractor_implement_iv_tablet"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tractor_implement_iv_tablet"
        android:background="@drawable/grid_display_arrow" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/actual_speed_tv_tablet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/actual_speed_display_tablet"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
            android:text="Actual speed" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/action_to_be_taken_tablet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Brake" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/next_speed_tv_tablet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/next_speed_display_tablet"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Next Speed" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/actual_speed_display_tablet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/action_to_be_taken_tablet"
            android:background="@drawable/speed_border"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"                
            android:text="14" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/next_speed_display_tablet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/actual_speed_display_tablet"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/actual_speed_display_tablet"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/actual_speed_display_tablet"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/action_to_be_taken_tablet"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/speed_border"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"                
            android:text="16" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tractor_implement_iv_tablet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/tractor_implement" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you including your layout?

Comment: At the Bottom, with this     <include 
        android:id="@+id/speed_display_layout"
        layout="@layout/display_tablet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_below="@+id/zoom_out" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"   
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

Comment: At the bottom of what?

Comment: Ath the bottom of Main Layout (The first xml which I posted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/zoom_out"
```

Take out that and then alignt to base line the images.